# cling 2.0.1 on Android - NoClassDefFoundError NetworkAddressFactoryImpl$1

Tags: android, upnp

I'm not the first one to have this problem, and Cling author isn't very user friendly to say the least. He just tells people to RTFM. And I swore an oath to never RTM. So... I have all dependencies in my gradle:

```
compile files('libs/jetty-client-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-continuation-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-http-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-io-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-security-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-server-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-servlet-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-util-8.1.17.v20150415.jar')
compile files('libs/servlet-api-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar')
compile files('libs/cling-core-2.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/cling-support-2.0.1.jar')
```

And yet what I get is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fourthline/cling/transport/impl/NetworkAddressFactoryImpl$1
        at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.NetworkAddressFactoryImpl.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkAddressFactoryImpl.java:145)
        at org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl.enable(RouterImpl.java:131)
        at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidRouter.enable(AndroidRouter.java:92)
        at org.fourthline.cling.UpnpServiceImpl.<init>(UpnpServiceImpl.java:87)
        at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl$1.<init>(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
        at org.fourthline.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.onCreate(AndroidUpnpServiceImpl.java:54)
        at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoUpnpService.onCreate(XenoUpnpService.java:109)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2634)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need servlet-api-3.0.jar

found out after days of internet researches.. : http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2013/03/12/jar-dependencies-if-you-plan-to-use-the-cling-upnp-library-in-your-android-project/

Answer (score 1):

you also need

```
compile files('libs/seamless-http-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/seamless-util-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/seamless-xml-1.1.1.jar')
```

Got them [here](http://4thline.org/m2/org/seamless/)